# Moment generating function of a constant multiple of a random varaible

Tags: probability, random-variable, moment-generating-function

Let $Y$ be a random variable which is a function of another random variable $X$, such that $Y=aX$, where $a$ is a constant. Is it possible that the moment generating function (MGF) of $Y$, is given by,

$$
\phi_Y(s)=[\phi_X(s)]^a, \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

where $\phi_X(s)$ is the MGF of $X$.

For our analysis, let us consider that the MGF of $Y$, by definition, is given by,

$$
\phi_Y(s)=E[e^{sY}]=E[e^{asX}]=\phi_X(as) \tag{2}\label{2},
$$

i.e. $\phi_Y(s)$ can be obtained by replacing $s$ by $as$ in $\phi_X(s)$. From $(\ref{2})$, it also follows that $(\ref{1})$ is not true i.e.

$$
\phi_Y(s) \neq [\phi_X(s)]^a, \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

Therefore, according to the above analysis, $\phi_Y(s)=[\phi_X(s)]^a$ is not possible for any probability distribution. However, I am not sure. It will be helpful if someone can shed further light on it.

Comment: There seems to be a gap: why does (2) imply (1) is not true?  In fact, there *are* random variables for which (1) holds: they are all almost surely constant.

Comment: $f(as)=f(s)^a$ is a functional equation with the solutions $f(s)=e^{ks}$ for some $k$, or perhaps $f(x)=0$, though you can ignore the last possibility for a moment generating function since you also need $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @whuber You mean (1) holds for random variables which are constant. This is confusing for me. Can you please explain with some example?

Comment: @Henry So, (1) will hold for, say, exponential distribution, $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$?

Comment: No: a moment generating function $e^{ks}$ corresponds to $P(X=k)=1$.  Meanwhile an exponential  distribution with rate $\lambda$ has moment generating function $\frac \lambda{\lambda-s}$.